# Is there any way to get real time document content without authorization?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-api

I'm using this method https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/get to get a real time document. However, it requires authorization.

Non realtime files can be retrieved by:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

which doesn't require authorization.

Is there any way to get a real-time document content without authorization considering I'm publicly sharing the file?

Answer (score 2):

No, you must provide an oauth token.  It needs to know which app is accessing the document to give the right realtime document.